# Rinkeby TxReceipt Status: Fail. Why?

Tags: transactions, contract-debugging, ipfs, infura, rinkeby

I'm trying to work out why some Rinkeby transactions of mine are failing. For example, https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x8746e41d51bb68df2649052c274ded300b9e5af7f820d9a856b7d199ba9e8fa4. I have no idea how to debug that transaction, so any pointers/advice would be very welcome.

fyi, I'm using infura's public API in an attempt to sidestep my organisation's firewall - thus, my dApp is deployed on IPFS at https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZetixYe97BStJZBbVH3woFEFrHzCMcuyak9JoCw4mjyx/#/, and it connects to Rinkeby via `window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rinkeby.infura.io))`. I 'think' that's okay, right?

Comment: I am sorry i dont have reputation to comment for your question. Can you share chucnk of code of your smart contract which you are calling. We can identify error.

Comment: If you follow that link, you'll find the bytecode of the contract.

Comment: Here's the VM stack trace - https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x8746e41d51bb68df2649052c274ded300b9e5af7f820d9a856b7d199ba9e8fa4

Can anyone explain that to me? Does it show the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This was failing because my contracts had the 'onlyOwner' modifier. Now, on a local, test network, that was fine because the contract creator and contract users were one and the same. However, that was no longer true on rinkeby.